# Connecting to MS-SQL using Jruby on Rails and Windows

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to connect to MS-SQL Server using Jruby. Previously I was running on Ruby on rails using Tiny-TDS gem and everything was fine. I developed the app that way.

Now, the requirement is for me to deploy on a Tomcat server, and so I was trying to use the Warbler Gem so that I can create a warble of the App that I have and then deploy in on Tomcat. I realized that for that I will need Jruby, but Jruby does not support Tiny-Tds. So I tried the `activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter` gem in various combinations but nothing is working.

My Gem file is as below:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
#Added gems
gem 'render_csv'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'


 if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
   gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
 else
   gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
 end

gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem  'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'

#gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', platform: :jruby
gem 'activerecord'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.9'




#Finish Added gems
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
   gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.3.pre1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'mocha', group: :test
```

Database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: <%="jdbc" if RUBY_ENGINE=="jruby"%>
  host: Remote_Host
  database: Database_InstanceName
  username: ***
  password: ***
  driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://Remote_Host:1433;databaseName=Database_InstanceName;integratedSecurity=true;
  conn: java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url, "Username", "Password")
```

Currently, I'm facing the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host Remote_Host, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port."

I have tried everything possible, I'm a newbie to Rails.

Am I missing something? A gem that can easily connect to MS-SQL from JRuby maybe? SQL Server is up and running on that instance, Firewall permissions are ok and all ports are set to 1433. However, while using Tiny-TDS, my database.yml was as below:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: Remote_Host
  port: 1021
  database: Remote_InstanceName
  username: ***
  password: ***
```

**Jruby version**: jruby 9.0.0.0.rc1 (2.2.2) 2015-06-10 a0bf3b3 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 2
5.45-b02 on 1.8.0_45-b15 +jit [Windows 7-amd64]
**Java Version**: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
**Rails 4.2.1**
**Ruby Version:** ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
OS Windows 7.

Would it be advisable to move to a Linux OS?

Comment: Finally, I figured it out. It was mostly a connection string issue and also a couple of version mismatch errors that I was facing which kept sidetracking me. Rails 4.1.9 is what works for me. 4.2.x seems to not work properly with activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem.
Database.yml:
adapter: jdbc
url: jdbc:sqlserver://Remote_Host:1021;databaseName=Database_InstanceName
I was using the wrong port number. Just posting it here so that maybe someone might find it useful